# ADC - LVDS/LVCMOS Interface

Tags: texas-instruments

I want to use the ADS58B18 from Texas Instruments. This ADC is differential and the outputs can set to either LVDS or LVCMOS with programming an internal register.

I have a question regarding the clock inputs and outputs.
Lets say I am programming the ADC to use LVDS outputs. Is it still possible to clock the ADC with a LVCMOS signal or does it have to be a LVDS clock now?

Thanks

Comment: The datasheet will answer that.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. It's a good idea to include the link to the datasheet that you're using. It saves us a search and it means that we're all using the same one. Hit the [edit] link.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads58b18.pdf), the pin functionality of the clock input does not change regardless of which mode you are using:

[image: Pinout is same in both CMOS and LVDS modes]

The clock signal is always a differential input. However it is possible to drive it from an LVCMOS signal by AC coupling and applying a DC offset as shown later in the datasheet. The LVDS/CMOS mode selection has no bearing on this ability.

[image: Driving Clock input]

In this configuration (single-ended input) you are actually making a pseudo-differential signal with a common mode offset that keeps changing, though the performance of this will be worse in terms of jitter performance and is not recommended for high speed sampling.

Comment: Thats the answer I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Hey Tom, I have another question regarding the input clock. The data sheet only says that Vpp = 700mV, which is +-350mV, Vcm = 1.7V. Is it possible to use a LVDS clock with Vpp = 700mV and Vcm = 1V?